# Lagom begin processing of source at startup

Tags: java, lagom

In my current scenario I have a file source from Alpakka that is supposed to produce file record events that I am publishing to a topic. The topic can be subscribed to from other services to receive the read events. In most of the examples I have seen so far there was an external event that triggered a chain of services to be invoked, however in my case I want the Alpakka system to start on its own to read files and publish events to the topic. Where would I start this in my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start this source, you'll want to wire it up in the application cake using some dependency injection framework; Lagom typically uses macwire for scala and Guice for java.

For more information about dependency injection, see [the docs](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/ComponentTechnologies.html) and for an example of wiring up a component similar to your source, see the [online-auction](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/9e5483daa87117117495b06b11752e2cb3af9c34/bidding-impl/src/main/java/Module.java#L17) example.

Comment: The `asEagerSingleton` is what I needed, I was wrongfully looking for something on the same level as the `bindService` methods :)